# Wifi Not Connecting - Cyanogenmod 10 TF101

Tags: wi-fi, cyanogenmod, connection-issues, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I just installed Cyanogenmod 10 on my Transformer TF101 and every time I try to connect to my home network, it says 'Connecting...' then it goes to 'Saved, secured with WPA' without the internet connection.

Comment: Any debug log (logcat or router log)? Otherwise it's hard to guess, with the crystal ball broken...

Comment: If you have MAC blacklist on your AP, check if the MAC has changed when you've installed CM10. Also check your WPA passphrase.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after flashing it with CM 10 Nightly, but after debugging on settings, I found a fix. I don't know if it's a bug or what, but what I did was:

1. 'forget' my network
2. Connect to it again (**make sure your security key is entered correctly**)
3. If still says, "saved, secured with WPA", don't hesitate, you're still not done
4. On your Wi-Fi window, press your menu button
5. Choose "Advanced"
6. There should be a "Wi-Fi frequency band" choice, make sure it's on "auto"
7. Still not working? Underneath the "Wi-Fi frequency band", there should be "Wi-Fi region code".
8. I don't know if yours has a choice selected, but mine didn't. I chose "United States" and *voila*, when I went back, it showed "connected" and my Wi-Fi sign finally showed on my status bar

Comment: The "Wifi region code" part solved my problem. Thanks!